# jquery show/hide for multiple groups of divs

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery to show and hide divs which works great with just one group of divs. But now I want to have multiple groups of these divs and display the first div of each group even if you change the radio button from another group. I however cannot seem to get the script to show first div of each group after changing the radio button in another group.

Heres my Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    $('.content').each(function () {
        $('.trigger').change(function () {
            $('.content').hide();
            $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
        });
    });

    $('input[type=radio]:first', this).attr('checked', true);
};
</script>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="1 trigger" data-rel="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="2 trigger" data-rel="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="3 trigger" data-rel="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" class="4 trigger" data-rel="4" />

</div>
<div id="firstgroup">
    <div class="1 content">text 1</div>
    <div class="2 content">text 2</div>
    <div class="3 content">text 3</div>
    <div class="4 content">text 4</div>
</div>

<div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="group2" class="5 trigger" data-rel="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" class="6 trigger" data-rel="6" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" class="7 trigger" data-rel="7" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" class="8 trigger" data-rel="8" />
</div>
    <div id="secondgroup">
    <div class="5 content">text 5</div>
    <div class="6 content">text 6</div>
    <div class="7 content">text 7</div>
    <div class="8 content">text 8</div>
</div>
```

and finally just the styles

```
<style>
 .none {
    display:none;
  }
 </style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94K3P/3/

Comment: You have a number of syntax issues, among them a misuse of the trigger method and multiple ID values. You're also acting on change of plain divs, which aren't editable.

Comment: so you want the .change event to show the first div in each group?? what else?? your ID's shouldnt have spaces in them either i think. (pls someone confirm if its ok to have spaces in IDS)

Comment: I want to show the value for each of the groups of divs and if you change the radio button in the first group the value for the second group must not be affected

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/94K3P/8

```
$('.trigger').change(function () {
    $('.content.' + $(this).data('rel')).show().siblings('.content').not(this).hide();
});

$('.trigger:first-child').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('checked', true).trigger('change');
});
```

I'm still not sure I understand your goal, but maybe this is close.

Comment: That's halfway there all it need to do now is have the first radio in each group selected by default when the page loads

Comment: something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/94K3P/6/) but want the lines $(".1").prop("checked", true).change(); and $(".5").prop("checked", true).change(); to be dynamic so I don't need to write one for each group

Comment: Answer updated. It was pretty much right already, but your original HTML wasn't properly set up.